# Automated Testing on website with no elements / Xpath

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, automated-tests

Are you aware of any test automation tool that can handle a website that has no elements / xpaths / id's (basically no DOM). If I check DOM Explorer (IE browser) there are only 'script' paths.

Devs told me that those screens are some sort of .NET internal system app (check screenshot) [image: Looks like that's all I can see on DOM Explorer]

I would not prefer to use some mouse recording tools or text recognition, but rather go for some script to manage those. Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser? How do you get that screenshot? Is it from devtool?

Comment: It's IE11 emulated to IE10, yes I am using devtool. Unfortunately I cannot post full screenshot due to some policies :)

Comment: I found that TestMaker software is able to cope with some heavy websites. Any one had experience with it? How is it compatible with selenium?

Comment: Is it a silverlight application?

Comment: Also please keep in mind that you better _not_ add code as image but its textual representation. Because not everyone is able/allowed to see images.

Comment: My further research gives me info that this is some JavaScript enabled by ActiveX script called from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that in your case the Flash files (which are closed files) are rendered in a container on a webpage.

> website that has no elements / xpaths / id's (basically no DOM)

For ex Flash player on Mozilla and Chrome and on ActiveX control in IE. Selenium relies heavily on JS communications (via JSON Wire protocol) and DOM in order to work as expected.

If I had to do it - I would try with [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) integration, so I could keep my initial approach and current setup (assuming you already had invested in such).

You didn't say what language you're using, so [here](http://selenium-suresh.blogspot.bg/2014/01/sikuli-automation-tool-integration-with.html) and [here](http://learn-automation.com/integrate-sikuli-with-selenium-webdriver/) are JAVA based implementations. I have used successfully C# based [sikuli4net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/) in the past to test ActionScript bingo games.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I will have to go for sikuli, yet tools that seem to cooperate with ActiveX are TestComplete and Ranorex - both commercial and maybe I will try to achieve something with trial versions